# Out of memory on a rather small matrix

Tags: matlab

I am doing motion detection on a fairly small video. 56 frames of 288x384xRGB. I keep two copies of it, so it should amount to about 40 Mb tops, including my other variables.

Now, this line gives me an out of memory error

```
output = uint8(zeros(this.videoHeight,2.*this.videoWidth,3,size(this.originalFrames,4)));
```

typing memory reports

```
 >> memory
Maximum possible array:             202 MB (2.114e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    863 MB (9.045e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              527 MB (5.526e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             3071 MB (3.220e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
>>
```

I'm new to MATLAB, but not totally new to programming. What am i not understanding?

***EDIT***
So i did som disp'ing:

```
        disp(this.videoHeight)
        disp(2.*this.videoWidth)
        disp(size(this.originalFrames,4))
```

produces:

```
288

768

54
```

So, it is actually smaller than i suggested...

Comment: Try breaking each of those arguments up. See what this.videoHeight, this.videoWidth,size(this.originalFrames,4) all actually equal. It could be that one of these is larger than you think.

Comment: This is important: use `zeros(data,'uint8')` instead of `uint8(zeros(data))`. This will initialize directly with `uint8` instead of initializing with `double` and then converting to `uint8` as your code is doing. Also can you directly output the size of the data instead of assuming what the size will be?

Comment: I wonder if could be attempting to initialize the zero matrix in double precision and only **then** convert it to uint8. It sounds inefficient I know, but perhaps that's what's happening. Edit: jucestain just beat me to it :).

Comment: @Stuart, I just ran the same code, substituting in the constants, and it was able to run fine with the same amount of RAM. It is definitely inefficient and doing as you said, but that's not what is causing this particular problem.

Comment: @KyleRogers this suggests the "constants" you're using are probably smaller than the actually size you're giving to `zeros`. Run the code but right before add `disp(this.videoHeight,2.*this.videoWidth,3,size(this.originalFrames,4)` and tell us the output

Comment: @jucestain ... Yes, that was my point. I used the constants that mickey provided (288x384x3x56) which should be what is being used as the parameters, but apparently they are not.

Comment: @KyleRogers My bad, I confused you with OP.

Comment: A solution is up for grabs, people! @jucestain seem to have been first at suggesting the correct solution. Stuart is a close second, and also provided a neat little calculation in a comment to an answer. The first one to put down the correct answer as a proper answer will be awarded the solution! Thanks a bunch guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
zeros(..., 'uint8')
```

rather than

```
uint8(zeros(...))
```

to avoid creating the array in double-precision first, and then copying it to a `uint8` array.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked in detail but I would be surprised if there weren't quite a bit of overhead imposed by Matlab.  You're probably using a lot more memory than you might suspect.

Try dialing down the number of frames you process to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Matlab is definitely capable of handling 40 Mb without an issue. More likely, he is doing something wrong with his calculations that is causing it to be much larger than he thinks. That said, 56 frames of 288x384x3 should not be an issue with 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight.